# seleccionar varios checkbox al filtrar el resultado por AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Necesito seleccionar varios checkbox que no están juntos y ponerlos en un `input` tipo `text`, logré que al hacer el filtrado de "estados" y seleccionarlos me los pusiera en el `input`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al realizar otra búsqueda me borra los `checkbox` antes elegidos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Script para buscar dinámicamente los estados

```
<script>
  function buscar() {
    var textoBusqueda = $("input#busqueda").val();
    if (textoBusqueda != "") {
      $.post("prueba_buscar.php", {valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda}, function(mensaje) {
        $("#resultadoBusquedaEstado").html(mensaje);
      }); 
    } 
    else { 
      p= "_";
      $.post("prueba_buscar.php", {valorBusqueda: p}, function(mensaje) {
        $("#resultadoBusquedaEstado").html(mensaje);
      });
    };
  };
</script>
```

Script para agrupar los `checkbox` seleccionados

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.check').click(function() {
    var ids;
    ids = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('id');
   }).get();

   $('#status1').val(ids.join(', '));
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Como estas guardando los id de los ya seleccionado, cuando agregues los checkbox con el metodo `.html()`, itera sobre cada id para buscar el checkbox y lo marcas:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   var ids = []

  $('.check').click(function() {  
    ids = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('id');
   }).get();

   $('#status1').val(ids.join(', ')); 
  });


  function marcarSeleccionados(){
        // iteramos cada id de los seleccionados
        for(var i = 0; i < ids.length;i++)
        {
            // buscamos el checkbox y lo marcamos
            $("#"+ids[i]).attr("checked",true);
        }
   }

  window.buscar = function() {
    var textoBusqueda = $("input#busqueda").val();
    if (textoBusqueda != "") {
      $.post("prueba_buscar.php", {valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda}, function(mensaje) {
        $("#resultadoBusquedaEstado").html(mensaje);
        marcarSeleccionados();
      }); 
    } 
    else { 
      p= "_";
      $.post("prueba_buscar.php", {valorBusqueda: p}, function(mensaje) {
        $("#resultadoBusquedaEstado").html(mensaje);
        marcarSeleccionados();
      });
    };
  };

});
</script>
```

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar